# Laurent series of $\frac1{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I had an exam question that has been troubling me. It looks simple, but I cannot seem to be able to figure this out.

> How can I find the Laurentian series expansion of $\frac1{1-z}$ in the region $|z+2|<3$?

Comment: If a series in powers of $z+2$ confuses you, change variables to $w=z+2$  do it in powers of $w$.  Then at the end change back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, try the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-z} &= \frac{1}{3 - (z+2)} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{1- (z+2)/3} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z+2}{3} \right)^n
\end{align*}

This is a standard trick by the way, in the end you only need to rewrite it in order to make use of the geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {1}{1-z}$
centered at $z = -2$

$\frac {1}{3-(z+2)}\\
\frac {\frac 13}{1-\frac {(z+2)}{3}}$

$\frac 13 \sum_\limits{i=0}^{\infty} (\frac {z+2}{3})^i$